# texture 3D on cylinder or sapling tree

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]Hello I have been working for a while
with Blender 3.3.1, and I encounter
anomalies, or misunderstanding
from me, I put on my onedrive
a small version, for which I
encounters a difficulty in rendering a
3D texture, on a sphere, or a plane
I have no difficulty in making the
3D texture, whereas with a cylinder
or a pov-Cylinder, or a tree coming
from Sapling Tree, the 3D rendering
is not there??

Here is the OneDrive link:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqveJNeoV8EAkiQWmcVbQ-9eNb63?e=ARwpKZ

Comment: Have you subdivided the cylinder ? True displacement only works when there is enough geometry

Comment: Thank's it will help